# I need to change two words to arabic words in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, wordpress-theming

I need to change "Last updated on" and "Posted on" From the code below to another words in arabic.

This code is part of the "template-tags.php" file which is part of the WordPress theme files

I just tried replacing the words but it didn't work for me

It just looks like this"����������"

```
<?php if ( get_theme_mod('show_post_date', '1') == 1 ) : ?>
<div class="entry-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span >
 
<?php $u_time = get_the_time('U');
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 60) {

echo "Last updated on ";       // here

the_modified_time('Y-m-d');
}
else {echo "Posted on ";       // here

the_time('Y-m-d');
} ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: What change must be made in the code to work with Arabic words

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem with the code. You can apply these changes to see if it works.

Using `htmlentities`

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod('show_post_date', '1') == 1) : ?>
    <div class="entry-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>

    <?php $u_time = get_the_time('U');
    $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
    if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 60) {

        $text = 'آخر تحديث في';

        echo htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");       // here

        the_modified_time('Y-m-d');
    } else {

        $text = 'نشر على';
        echo htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");       // here

        the_time('Y-m-d');
    } ?>

<?php
endif;
```

Notice that I

```
<? Php
endif;
```

I added myself, it will probably be different from your code and still continue.

Or you can use `utf8_encode` like this:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod('show_post_date', '1') == 1) : ?>
    <div class="entry-date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><span>

    <?php $u_time = get_the_time('U');
    $u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
    if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 60) {

        $text = 'آخر تحديث في';

        echo utf8_encode($text);       // here

        the_modified_time('Y-m-d');
    } else {

        $text = 'نشر على';
        echo utf8_encode($text);       // here

        the_time('Y-m-d');
    } ?>

<?php
endif;
```

And if the above did not work.
You should check to see if there is a `UTF-8` meta on your page. `<meta charset="utf-8">` This meta should be in your `header.php` file. If not, add it.
If you did all the work but did not answer, use a standard Arabic or Persian font

Comment: Thanks for help.
It didn't work with me.
Already there <meta charset="utf-8"> in header.php.

Comment: hi @Mustafajabbar .
This looks very bad.
Have you used other methods?

Comment: Hi @morteza-barati
The problem was solved in an alternative way.
I used "Unused phrases" in theme.
I changed its translation with Poedit.

Comment: hi @Mustafajabbar Yes, Sure.
I did not remember at all, thank you, we could do all this with the translation function. Thanks for the reminder